# Do some functions when branching by Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Routes` branchiing like this below

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<TopPage />} />
          <Route path={`/dev`} element={<TopPage />} />
```

Now I want to do some task depending on url like this below.

(This code is wrong, but I hope it can explain what I want to do)

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} dothis={var variable="prod";render(<TopPage>) />
          <Route path={`/dev`} dothis={var variable="dev";render(<TopPage>)/>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're wanting props

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<TopPage environment="prod" />} />
          <Route path={`/dev`} element={<TopPage environment="dev" />} />
```

Then in your `TopPage` component

```
const TopPage = ({environment}) => {
  // use `environment` here
}
```

If you're using TypeScript, you should look into using an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) to prevent making typos in the name or forgetting the possible valid values.

Comment: It works perfect, I didn't notice to use `props`

Answer (score 0):

You should [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) or [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) (or you could just write code in your component inline for the useMemo case) depending on your use case.

```js
let location = useLocation();

const isDev = useMemo(() => {
  return location.pathname.startsWith("/dev");
}, [location]);
// could also be just 
const isDev = location.pathname.startsWith("/dev");

useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname.startsWith("/dev") {
    console.log("DEV ENABLED");
  }
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Thank you it also helpful, `useLocation()`

Comment: However in my case, using `props` environmet is suitable ,but this also helpful.